# Interrupted Thread is removed by Thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, quartz-scheduler, threadpool

I am working on Quartz framework,where I have to trigger the job in every 10 secs and every job hit the service in 10 sec..for more clarity please have a look of below code.

## Main class

```
public class CronTriggerExample 
{
public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception
{
    JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(HelloJob.class)
            .withIdentity("dummyJobName", "group1").build();

    Trigger trigger = TriggerBuilder
            .newTrigger()
            .withIdentity("dummyTriggerName", "group1")
            .withSchedule(
                    CronScheduleBuilder.cronSchedule("0/10 * * * * ?"))
            .build();
    Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
    scheduler.start();
    scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);

   }
}
```

## Job Class

I am running infinite while loop for my testing condition.

```
public class HelloJob implements InterruptableJob
{
   AtomicReference<Thread> runningThread = new AtomicReference<Thread>();   
   AtomicBoolean stopFlag = new AtomicBoolean(false);
   static Date outcallExecuteJobRunTime = new Date();
   static boolean prvJobRunning = false;
   private static AtomicBoolean prvJobExecuted = new AtomicBoolean(true);

public void execute(JobExecutionContext context)
throws JobExecutionException {
      long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
      try{
        System.out.println("["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"] Running OutCallExecutor job");

      Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
      cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, -20);     

      Date compareDate = cal.getTime();

 SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
      boolean isThreadExceededRunTime = compareDate.after(outcallExecuteJobRunTime);

      System.out.println("compare date is  : "+df.format(compareDate));

System.out.println("Running Thread is "+runningThread); 
      if(! isThreadExceededRunTime)
          System.out.println("Previous job is running withing time limit");      

      if(!prvJobExecuted.get() ){

    //Check if prev job is still running? If yes, then the thread is hanged/blocked - 
        //so interrupt it and set previous job to true
          if(isThreadExceededRunTime){
              System.out.println("Previouse job is running more the limit");
             interrupt();
              return;
          }else{
              System.out.println("Normal exit. Previous job is not executed yet");
                  return;
          }

      }
      prvJobExecuted.set(false);
      this.runningThread.set(Thread.currentThread());       
      System.out.println("Running Thread is "+runningThread.get().getName()); 
          outcallExecuteJobRunTime = new Date();
        System.out.println("OutCallExcecutor :: outcallExecuteJobRunTime : "+outcallExecuteJobRunTime); 
          System.out.println("Running OutCallExecutor executed.");
          while(1 == 1){}


    }catch(Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println("OutCallExecutor :: Exception occured while OutCallExecutor. Exception "+e.getMessage());
    prvJobExecuted.set(true);

  }
      prvJobExecuted.set(true);
}

@Override
public void interrupt() throws UnableToInterruptJobException {

    //System.out.println("HelloJob.interrupted BZZZZZZZZZZ(). Stopping running Thread "+runningThread.get().getName());
    System.out.println("===1=====");
    prvJobExecuted.set(true);
    System.out.println("===2=====");
     Thread thread = runningThread.getAndSet(null);
          System.out.println("===1===== Thread is "+thread);
     if (thread != null){
         if(thread.getName() != null){
             System.out.println("===1===== Thread Name is   "+thread.getName());
         }
         thread.interrupt();
     }
  }

}
```

Just for understanding I am printing the output of program

## OutPut

```
[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1] Running OutCallExecutor job
compare date is  : 2016-07-21 23:01:00
Running Thread is null
Previous job is running withing time limit
Running Thread is DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1
OutCallExcecutor :: outcallExecuteJobRunTime : Thu Jul 21 23:01:20 IST 2016
Running OutCallExecutor executed.
[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-2] Running OutCallExecutor job
OutCallExecutor compare date is  : 2016-07-21 23:01:10
Running Thread is Thread[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1,5,main]
Previous job is running withing time limit
Normal exit. Previous job is not executed yet
======================================================
====================================================
[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-3] Running OutCallExecutor job
compare date is  : 2016-07-21 23:01:20
Running Thread is Thread[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1,5,main]
Previous job is running withing time limit
Normal exit. Previous job is not executed yet
======================================================
====================================================
[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-4] Running OutCallExecutor job
compare date is  : 2016-07-21 23:01:30
Running Thread is Thread[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1,5,main]
Previouse job is running more the limit
===1=====
===2=====
===1===== Thread is Thread[DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1,5,main]
===1===== Thread Name is   DefaultQuartzScheduler_Worker-1
```

When I interrupted the WorkerThread-1 then its not assigning to thread pool again and it went loss,while I want to thread pool default size should remain same.
Can anyone please help me to kill or stop the thread by which Thread pool size will not affect as in above written program I loose whole Thread pool and last thread never will interrupt as new job will not hit the service.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Wow. I don't understand what you are trying to do. Shouldn't your task (job) do its job well and not do anything with the thread in which it is run? After the job is executed (normally or exceptionally), the thread should return to the pool. Why are you interrupting it?

Comment: in case if my job got stuck and it will run for long time without any exception or error then it will not allow to run the other job due to that I have interrupt that specific job and have to send it again to threadpool.

Comment: I put infinite while loop for not to allow other thread to access it and in that case it should interrupt and send it back to ThreadPool which is not happening now.I hope..I make myself clear,if not please let me know,i'll try to elaborate it more

Comment: Well, if your _task_ is expected to take long, be patient. If there is a bug (or for some other reason), you want to interrupt the thread that runs your task, then it is a different thing. The bottom line is the threads from a thread pool that run your tasks are owned by the thread pool and they are best managed by the thread pool implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread does not appear to check if it is interrupted. Try

```
while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
```

instead of

```
while(1 == 1)
```

Comment: actually I am just putting infinite while loop to keep job running for long time..I have to interput the job which  is running through this infinite while loop and then have to interput it and assign back to Threadpool..In above OUPUT you can see 4th workerThread interputted the 1st WorkerThread.Now whole process repeat and workerThread-1 will not there and my Thread pool capacity is reduce by 1 Thread.